# Simultaneous writing in a file using c++

Tags: c++, windows

How to write in a file from multiple threads simultaneously without taking a lock on the file.I have tries the shared read and write approaches.The problem ewith this approach is that to write on the file i need to take a lock. so can anyone help me with a solution in which i don't have to take a lock.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it work? How didn't it work? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: "How to write in a file from multiple threads" - please elaborate. updating? appending? reading? separate locations? what are you doing? why?

Comment: You can either 1) take a lock and make other wait on it in order to write, 2) make a blocking call to a function which handles the file writing, or 3) close the file after each access & reopen for the next.

Comment: Might be quite hard without holding a lock, depending on exactly what you are writing.

Comment: And can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can use a cooperative model in which each thread knows when it can write to the file. I don't like it, but it will do.

Comment: Use 1 component which writes to the file. Now you need to make sure that the component is threadsafe.

Comment: Basically different threads would have to enter some information at the end of the file.The size of the data would not be fixed.

Comment: Have one thread that updates a file, and push the data to that worker.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's very rare that parallel writes are beneficial from a performance perspective (in particular, writing large blocks of data often makes performance WORSE), one solution may be to have a separate write-thread, with some sort of queue of packets with data to write, where multiple threads can add to the queue and only one thread is reading out of the queue and writing to the file.

Now, of course, you have the problem of perhaps needing locking in the queue instead. There are some multiple write lockless queues (but typically not strictly "waitless", just that there is no big lock, instead a compare-exchange or similar is used in a loop to ensure the correct data is written). Further, the lock to copy data into the queue is MUCH shorter than the time it takes to write the data to file.

You may need to have flow-control on the queue ("wait if the queue has more than X bytes to write" or some such), so that you don't have a dozen threads all writing new data to the file as fast as they can and end up filling all avilable memory - but this would only be needed if you have a good chance of several threads all writing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Always writing to a file from multiple thread simultaneously will results in undetectable behavior. Either file may corrupt or application may crash.

**Two choices:**

- Single Write thread for writing.
- Go with Lock.

In worst situation, You can try to take EXCLUSIVE lock. If you got EXCLUSIVE lock then you can write. Otherwise take a loop until you got the EXCLUSIVE lock.